# why calling function/method overload as static polymorphism in c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

On my mind, polymorphism is do different thing for some base class type at runtime. 
As for overload is also polymorphism was first listened today, such as:

```
void A(int a){}
void A(int a, int b){}
```

Why `A` be called static polymorphism?I'm just wonder the concept.
Does there also have a virtual table?

Comment: No, it does not use a virtual table, as *static* means it is resolved at compile-time. The wikipedia article on [Function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) summarizes it as: *"When overloading a method, you are really just making a number of different methods that happen to have the same name."*

Comment: I don't think this is an example of static polymorphism. Some function overloading is used as static polymorphism, some other function overloading is just not.

Comment: @NickyC, Could you show a example or explain what's the kind of overload is static polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism means, the callee is the one who decide how to do when it receives a message from the caller.

Think of a message "go forward 10 meters". If the callee is a person, the person does so by walking. If the callee is a car, the car does so by turning its wheels.

The idea of polymorphism does not specify what language features are involved, or when to make the decision of how to do. We can do it in runtime, using virtual function. We can do it in compile-time (static polymorphism), using function overloading, templates, or even evil preprocessor macros.

If we use virtual function:

```
MovableObject* ptr = get_person();
ptr->go_forward(10);

MovableObject* ptr2 = get_car();
ptr2->go_forward(10);
```

If we use function overloading:

```
void go_forward(Person& person, int distance);
void go_forward(Car& car, int distance);
```

---

Not all function overloading are used as polymorphism.

To demonstrate static polymorphism through overloading, consider two simple programs.

```
// Program 1
int a;
int b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
int sum = a + b;
std::cout << sum;

// Program 2
double a;
double b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
double sum = a + b;
std::cout << sum;
```

Wait. It looks like it does not involve overloading, does it?

Actually, there is overloading. Both programs involve an expression `a + b`. They both mean addition to us. But there is a difference: `+` in program 1 is compiled into the machine instruction of *integer addition*; `+` in program 2 is compiled into *floating point addition*. Both are addition, but the physical operations are very different.

Is it overloading? Yes, `+` is overloaded.

Is it polymorphism? Yes, `+` means the same thing to the caller for both cases, and the underlying operations are different.

Now consider another use of `+`.

```
// Program 3
std::string a;
std::string b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::string sum = a + b;
std::cout << sum;
```

Program 3 uses `+` too. But it is not addition anymore. It is now string concatenation.

Is it overloading? Yes, `+` is overloaded.

Is it polymorphism? No, the meaning is now different comparing to program 1 and 2. Addition and concatenation are very different things.

---

Another example.

Think of standard library containers.

```
vector<int> my_vector;
begin(my_vector);

list<double> my_list;
begin(my_list);
```

Is it overloading? Yes, `begin` is overloaded.

Is it polymorphism? Yes, both versions of `begin` returns an iterator pointing to the first element, even though the iterators are of different type.

How about this. A class representing a stopwatch, and a function `begin` start counting time.

```
Stopwatch my_watch;
begin(my_watch);
```

Is it overloading? Yes, `begin` is overloaded.

Is it polymorphism? Not this time. This `begin` is not to obtain an iterator. It just starts the stopwatch. The meaning is different so that it is not a form of polymorphism when it is considered with other `begin`s.

Comment: Thanks so detail and such examples but I have some wonder.Why string `+` operator and `begin(Stopwatch sw);`  is NOT? does the different of paramater(s) should have same base class, such as,  `begin(Iterator<T> param)`, even though `go_forward` has two function but it will be deal with same as `begin` in compile-time (so called polymorphism?). But `+` was really amazing....

Comment: @LoranceChen There is nothing to do with base class. Meaning matters. Adding integers and adding floating point numbers are both addition. But adding numbers and string concatenation are not the same thing.

Comment: em... whats the “same thing” based on？